# Install new plugin to Protégé

Tags: semantic-web, protege, shacl

I wish to install a new plugin to Protégé, that is not listed in the *default [Protégé plugin library](http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Protege_Plugin_Library)*.

Does anyone have any experience doing this, and may point me in the right direction? The plugin I wish to install is [SHACL4P](https://github.com/fekaputra/shacl-plugin/tree/shacl). If anyone knows about any other SHACL plugins for Protégé that I should check out, I gladly take any recommendations as well.

Answer (score 2):

A protégé plugin is a jar containing the required plugin.xml and able to be loaded as an OSGi module. If the code you wish to install is already packaged this way, you only need to copy the jar in the plugins folder inside protégé, and it will be picked up the next time you start protégé.

For libraries that are not packaged as plugins, the process is more complex and requires writing code as well. I recommend reading the documentation on the protégé website before doing that.